# GtkInfoBar doesn't show again after hide

Tags: python, gtk, glade, pygobject

I'm hide Gtk widget, then try to show it, but none of the methods "show()", "show_all()" or "show_now()" does't work. If not call "hide()" widget shows.

```
python 3.5.2
gtk3 3.20.8
pygobject-devel 3.20.1
```

test.py:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("gui.glade")
infoBar = builder.get_object("infoBar")
window = builder.get_object("window")
window.show_all()

infoBar.hide()

infoBar.show()

Gtk.main()
```

gui.glade: http://pastebin.com/xKFt1v84

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is a long-standing bug in GTK+ specific to GtkInfoBar. Monitor the linked bug report for more details, some workarounds (including one in Python that you can use for the time being) and to find out when it's fixed for real.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=710888)